# Bootstrap way of resizing components according to page size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there any **bootstrap way** to resize bootstrap components according to page size? Not hiding or showing it, I want same bootstrap component change its size according to the page size. 
For example I have button group that shows up `btn-group-lg` for large screens, and the same button group use `btn-group-sm` class for small screens.

Note: I know how to do it by using javascript, i ask only bootstrap way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, through media queries, you can also (lets say for divs) do col-sm-4 col-md-8 and depending on the display size the column will adjust size accordingly (and shift if not enough space is available).

check out http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

it even directly references the media queries I spoke of earlier.

If you need extreme fine grain control over the size of an element you should not be doing it directly with bootstrap.  Implement bootstrap via it's less css or sass build and add in what you need.  It's very easy to do and the site has detailed instructions to do so.

If you just want your own element to resize, and it's not a bootstrap element, then do so via an additional CSS file that you load in conjunction with the bootstrap framework.